# Android - Seekbar tick mark color not able to change

Tags: android, seekbar

I am using Discrete seekbar. I want to change the color of tick marks. I am trying like following.

```
<SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="10"
        android:thumbTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:tickMarkTint="@color/colorAccent"/>
```

And also I create style and applied in tickMark.

drw_bg_tickmark.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval"
    android:tint="@color/colorAccent">
    <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
    <size android:width="10dp"
        android:height="10dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
</shape>
```

Applied in seekbar

```
android:tickMark="@drawable/drw_bg_tickmark"
```

But I am not able to remove the gray ticks in the seek bar. Please help me on this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the gray ticks/balls you can just remove the style, and apply your drawable to `android:tickMark`

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="10"
    android:tickMark="@drawable/drw_bg_tickmark"
    android:thumbTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:tickMarkTint="@color/colorAccent"/>
```

Comment: If you have any idea about this question please let me know.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66125645/custom-seekbar-with-default-thumb

Answer (score 1):

create a style for your seekbar

```
 <resources>
        <style name="SeekBarWithoutSteps" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete">
            <item name="tickMark">@null</item>
        </style>
    </resources>



<SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        style="@style/SeekBarWithoutSteps"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="10"
        android:thumbTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:tickMarkTint="@color/colorAccent"/>
```

Comment: Can we do <item name="tickMark">@null</item> by programmatically by java?

Comment: seekBar.setTickMark(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.drw_bg_tickmark));

We can set tickMark drawable dynamically. This will require API level 24 and above.

Comment: Thanks Krishan for the answer. this is also working. But when I try with set programatically I am facing some issue. So I am going with Zain ans. If have any idea about the following question please let me know. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66125645/custom-seekbar-with-default-thumb